# Arduino WiFi UDP upload problems

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-ide

I recently got an arduino and wifi sheild but i am having trouble with the wifi library specifically the udp class. the connection and everything works fine when i dont have the WiFiUdp.h and cpp files in the folder. I can get on the internet, send data, get a green and blue light which establishes connection and data being sent. But the moment i include wifiudp.h in my sketch., I get a bunch of errors. the errors are listed below. I got my library from github, downloaded it, extracted and stuffed it into the library like i did with everything else on github. Its not my code because when i use the wifisendreceive example on the arduino website, i get the same errors when i upload it. something isnt working right in this 'master' arduino file from github. has anyone experienced the same issue i am dealing with and does anyone know how to fix this? I know as many errors as i get, its probably not including or defining something, i just dont know where and what. the errors explain where its not working but the problem is there is a bunch of them. here are the errors. thanks for anyone that can shed light on this udp class. By the way, this is just half of the errors. I am not allowed to send more than 3000 characters in the body. the errors are the same type just from different files, etc.

```
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::getSocket()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:26: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::getSocket()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:25: first defined here
c:/users/albertr/desktop/arduino-1.0.3/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:26: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::_server_port'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:25: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::hostByName(char const*, IPAddress&)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:227: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::hostByName(char const*, IPAddress&)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:194: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::status()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:224: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::status()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:191: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::encryptionType(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:217: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::encryptionType(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:184: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::RSSI(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:212: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::RSSI(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:179: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::SSID(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:207: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::SSID(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:174: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::scanNetworks()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:191: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::scanNetworks()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:158: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::encryptionType()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:187: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::encryptionType()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:154: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::RSSI()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:182: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::RSSI()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:149: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::BSSID(unsigned char*)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:173: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::BSSID(unsigned char*)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:140: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::SSID()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:170: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::SSID()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:137: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::gatewayIP()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:161: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::gatewayIP()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:128: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::subnetMask()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:154: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::subnetMask()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:121: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::localIP()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:147: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::localIP()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:114: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::macAddress(unsigned char*)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:140: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::macAddress(unsigned char*)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:107: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::disconnect()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:137: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::disconnect()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:104: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::begin(char*, char const*)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:82: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::begin(char*, char const*)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:82: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::begin(char*, unsigned char, char const*)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:63: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::begin(char*, unsigned char, char const*)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:62: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::begin(char*)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:43: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::begin(char*)'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:42: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::firmwareVersion()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:40: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::firmwareVersion()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:39: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::init()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:23: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::init()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:22: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::init()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:23: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::WiFiClass()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:22: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClass::init()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:23: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::WiFiClass()'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:22: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:26: multiple definition of `WiFiClass::_state'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:25: first defined here
WiFi\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFi.cpp:26: multiple definition of `WiFi'
WiFi1\WiFi.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFi.cpp:25: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:17: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::WiFiClient()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:17: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:17: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::WiFiClient()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:17: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:20: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::WiFiClient(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:20: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:20: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::WiFiClient(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:20: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::write(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:56: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::write(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:56: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::flush()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:121: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::flush()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:121: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::operator bool()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:164: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::operator bool()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:164: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::getFirstSocket()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:169: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::getFirstSocket()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:169: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::status()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:157: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::status()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:157: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::connected()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:142: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::connected()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:142: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::stop()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:126: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::stop()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:126: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::peek()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:112: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::peek()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:112: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::read()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:96: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::read()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:96: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::read(unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:106: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::read(unsigned char*, unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:106: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::available()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:88: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::available()'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:88: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:60: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:60: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::connect(IPAddress, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:32: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::connect(IPAddress, unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:32: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o: In function `WiFiClient::connect(char const*, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiClient.cpp:23: multiple definition of `WiFiClient::connect(char const*, unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiClient.cpp:23: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiClient.cpp.o:(.data._ZN10WiFiClient8_srcportE+0x0): multiple definition of `WiFiClient::_srcport'
WiFi1\WiFiClient.cpp.o:(.data._ZN10WiFiClient8_srcportE+0x0): first defined here
WiFi\WiFiServer.cpp.o: In function `WiFiServer':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp:12: multiple definition of `WiFiServer::WiFiServer(unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiServer.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiServer.cpp:12: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiServer.cpp.o: In function `WiFiServer':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp:12: multiple definition of `WiFiServer::WiFiServer(unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiServer.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiServer.cpp:12: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiServer.cpp.o: In function `WiFiServer::write(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp:66: multiple definition of `WiFiServer::write(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\WiFiServer.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiServer.cpp:65: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiServer.cpp.o: In function `WiFiServer::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp:71: multiple definition of `WiFiServer::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
WiFi1\WiFiServer.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiServer.cpp:70: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiServer.cpp.o: In function `WiFiServer::status()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp:62: multiple definition of `WiFiServer::status()'
WiFi1\WiFiServer.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiServer.cpp:61: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiServer.cpp.o: In function `WiFiServer::available(unsigned char*)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp:28: multiple definition of `WiFiServer::available(unsigned char*)'
WiFi1\WiFiServer.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiServer.cpp:27: first defined here
WiFi\WiFiServer.cpp.o: In function `WiFiServer::begin()':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi/WiFiServer.cpp:17: multiple definition of `WiFiServer::begin()'
WiFi1\WiFiServer.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1/WiFiServer.cpp:17: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `socket':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:10: multiple definition of `socket'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:10: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `close':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:11: multiple definition of `close'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:11: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `connect':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:12: multiple definition of `connect'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:12: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `disconnect':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:13: multiple definition of `disconnect'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:13: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `listen':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:14: multiple definition of `listen'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:14: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `send':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:15: multiple definition of `send'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:15: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `recv':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:16: multiple definition of `recv'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:16: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `sendto':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:17: multiple definition of `sendto'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:17: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `recvfrom':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:18: multiple definition of `recvfrom'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:18: first defined here
WiFi\utility\socket.c.o: In function `igmpsend':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/socket.c:20: multiple definition of `igmpsend'
WiFi1\utility\socket.c.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/socket.c:20: first defined here
WiFi\utility\server_drv.cpp.o: In function `ServerDrv::availData(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/server_drv.cpp:125: multiple definition of `ServerDrv::availData(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\utility\server_drv.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/server_drv.cpp:123: first defined here
WiFi\utility\server_drv.cpp.o: In function `ServerDrv::getClientState(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/server_drv.cpp:104: multiple definition of `ServerDrv::getClientState(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\utility\server_drv.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/server_drv.cpp:102: first defined here
WiFi\utility\server_drv.cpp.o: In function `ServerDrv::getServerState(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/server_drv.cpp:83: multiple definition of `ServerDrv::getServerState(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\utility\server_drv.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/server_drv.cpp:81: first defined here
WiFi\utility\server_drv.cpp.o: In function `ServerDrv::stopClient(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/server_drv.cpp:62: multiple definition of `ServerDrv::stopClient(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\utility\server_drv.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/server_drv.cpp:60: first defined here
WiFi\utility\server_drv.cpp.o: In function `ServerDrv::checkDataSent(unsigned char)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/server_drv.cpp:275: multiple definition of `ServerDrv::checkDataSent(unsigned char)'
WiFi1\utility\server_drv.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/server_drv.cpp:227: first defined here
WiFi\utility\server_drv.cpp.o: In function `ServerDrv::sendData(unsigned char, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/server_drv.cpp:248: multiple definition of `ServerDrv::sendData(unsigned char, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
WiFi1\utility\server_drv.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/server_drv.cpp:200: first defined here
WiFi\utility\server_drv.cpp.o: In function `ServerDrv::getDataBuf(unsigned char, unsigned char*, unsigned int*)':
C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi\utility/server_drv.cpp:173: multiple definition of `ServerDrv::getDataBuf(unsigned char, unsigned char*, unsigned int*)'
WiFi1\utility\server_drv.cpp.o:C:\Users\AlbertR\Desktop\arduino-1.0.3\libraries\WiFi1\utility/server_drv.cpp:176: first defined here
```

Comment: multiple definition means you are either linking the same symbols multiple times or you are have a header included multiple times without proper include guards. In your case it looks like you have a WiFi and WiFi1 folder containing the same library getting linked (linking the same symbols multiple times).

Comment: Joe, Yes, you are right on the money. I named my original Wifi as WiFi1 to distinguish itself from the Wifi library i downloaded from github. I didnt think they would interfere. Sure enough when i compiled it without WiFi1; it worked like a charm. Thank you for looking at this logically and figuring out what my mistake was. This helps a lot!

Comment: Joe please see this error title 
Arduino UDP Error WiFiUdp.cpp  that i posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

multiple definition means you are either linking the same symbols multiple times or you are have a header included multiple times without proper include guards. In your case it looks like you have a WiFi and WiFi1 folder containing the same library getting linked (linking the same symbols multiple times). – Joe